# Is it possible to restrict which programs can launch a wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a program launcher for a suite of wpf applications that I have made. The launcher will be used to log users into the applications as well as to perform various tests before launching the applications.

What I would like is to make it so that the applications can only be started by the launcher, and not run directly. Is there a way for me to check that the application's process has been started by the launcher rather than a user, perhaps in my AppStart()?

Comment: You could use a named pipe to perform inter-process communication to pass some "key" or perform some other validation.

Comment: Would there be a way to check that the program was only being started via the named pipe? And also wouldn't one be able to create another application with the same named pipe that bypassed this?

Comment: @AleksandrAlbert -- You need to research this yourself.  We're not going to do all the work for you.  Presumably the name of the pipe is only known by the parent application and the child applications (the ones that are being launched).  The children would of course launch no matter what, but they could terminate if they weren't started via the parent.

Comment: The launched application could used a named pipe and some kind of challenge/response to verify that it's launcher is "approved".

Comment: @roryap ok thanks for the input

Comment: @crashmastr Thanks I'll look more into the challenge/response model

Comment: It's never going to be 100% foolproof.  Someone could always write an application that mimicked the launcher.  They could use third-party tools to monitor the IPC activity and figure out what the magic pipe name is.  They could also decompile or reverse engineer the launcher app to figure it out or get the password.

Comment: What happens when your launcher says the database/server connection is okay, the app launches and the database/server/network goes down?  You still have to handle this in your app, so checking in the launcher is almost not worth it.  Many other (potential) issues with the approach you presented, but without knowing all the details, I of course cannot say this with 100% certainty.

Comment: Maybe you could look into signing your launcher with a strong-named key file and using reflection from the child applications to figure out if the caller is your preferred launcher application.

Comment: If your launcher was a host (sort of like MMC) and your exe's were addins/dlls then you might have something you could control much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach that could work for you.  You could sign your launcher assembly:

[image]

And then you could make it so that your child applications will terminate if they weren't run from your launcher application.

Here is some code for your child application(s) which makes use of [the Windows API NtQueryInformationProcess function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It obtains the parent process by first getting its process ID via `GetParentProcessID`, then it loads the assembly from that process and retrieves its full (i.e. "strong") name which contains your public key.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
private static extern int NtQueryInformationProcess(IntPtr processHandle, int processInformationClass, ref NtQueryInformationProcessProcessInformation processInformation, int processInformationLength, ref int returnLength);

/// <summary>
/// Return the process ID of the process that is the parent of this process, if any, or else return null.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Return the process ID of the process that is the parent of this process, if any, or else return null.</returns>
/// <remarks></remarks>
private static int? GetParentProcessID()
{
    var info = new NtQueryInformationProcessProcessInformation();
    var returnLength = 0;
    const int ProcessInfoClassProcessBasicInformation = 0;
    var status = NtQueryInformationProcess(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, ProcessInfoClassProcessBasicInformation, ref info, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(info), ref returnLength);
    var NTStatusSuccess = 0;
    if (status != NTStatusSuccess) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(status);

    try
    {
        return Process.GetProcessById(info.InheritedFromUniqueProcessId.ToInt32()).Id;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return new int?(); //not found.            
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A structure which is required by the <see cref="NtQueryInformationProcess"/> method.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks></remarks>
private struct NtQueryInformationProcessProcessInformation
{
    internal IntPtr Reserved1;
    internal IntPtr PebBaseAddress;
    internal IntPtr Reserved2_0;
    internal IntPtr Reserved2_1;
    internal IntPtr UniqueProcessId;
    internal IntPtr InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
var parentProcessID = GetParentProcessID();
var parentProcess = parentProcessID.HasValue ? Process.GetProcessById(parentProcessID.Value) : null;

if(parentProcess != null)
{
    try
    {
        var strongName = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(parentProcess.MainModule.FileName);

        // check your strong name to make sure it belongs to the launcher...
    }
    catch (System.BadImageFormatException e)
    {
        // not a .net assembly, so it couldn't be your launcher app.
    }
}
```

This is just a start, but you get the idea...

Comment: Hi thanks for taking the time to answer, this seems to be along the lines of what I'm looking for however the question has been put on hold, even though you are providing a useful answer. I look forward to hearing your further thoughts.

Comment: @AleksandrAlbert -- yes, the question is pretty broad which is why it was put on hold.  It would take too much to answer it.  I managed to get my answer in before it was put on hold.

Comment: @AleksandrAlbert -- I added some updates for your review.

Comment: many thanks this gives me a good place to start, I am currently reading up on strong key assemblies